# how to add lookup/choice field with data from Active Directory to Sharepoint custom content type

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, lookup

I am trying to create a custom content type in Sharepoint where one of the multiple choice fields needs to get data from Active Directory. I've been looking on Google but haven't found any good solutions. Probably I'd have to create a custom field type?

Thanks!

Comment: YOu have to be a bit more specific. What do you want to get from AD? a list of computers for instance, users, etc?

Comment: update: from AD i'm getting a list of bank branches

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [blog post](http://sharepoint.blog.hexun.com/7800600_d.html) on implementing this functionality with AD and Custom Field Types.

EDIT: [link](http://jack.whyyoung.com/blog/www-sharepointblogs-com-MainFeed-aspx-GroupID-3/Creating-Custom-Field-Types.htm) is dead, replaced

Comment: Do you have a link that works? This gets a "this domain is for sale" page.

Comment: new link updated, not sure if it is the same code but a very similar solution.